# SSRS/Report Builder - Sum of a field being dependent on a value of another

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder

this is what i want:
[image: ss1]

my problem is getting that last total. my data has tasks from 5000 - 9000 and they each have a description and budget etc ...

i am currently grouping and doing a total based on this expression in a calculated field:

```
Left(CStr(Fields!Task_Code.Value), 2) & "00"
```

it just strips the last 2 digits off the task and groups. so there is a subtotal for all 5100 and there is a subtotal for all 5200 etc ...

well now i need to group and total on ranges of tasks. so i need a group/total on 5100-5900 and a group/total for 6200-6500 and so on. its arbitrary so i would just like to provide a range, rinse and repeat. how can i do this? below is a screenshot of it as well:
[image: ss2]

the expression in the screenshot is just a switch statement for labels, its not the expression above.

Comment: how arbitrary are we talking? different each time it's ran, different every 6 months?

Comment: no like a one and done setup. ill put in the range once and thats it. i mentioned that only because there doesn't have to be a complex solution for the range other than me setting it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your above data, I would use a couple of Calculated Fields and apply two groupings based on these.

Using the above data (plus a few more rows for demonstration):

[image]

I've added two Calculated Fields:

**Group**

```
=Switch(Left(CStr(Fields!Task_Code.Value), 2) = "51", "Group1"
    , Left(CStr(Fields!Task_Code.Value), 2) = "52", "Group2"
    , Left(CStr(Fields!Task_Code.Value), 2) = "62", "Group3")
```

**Location**

```
=Switch(Fields!Task_Code.Value >= 5100 and Fields!Task_Code.Value <= 5900, "Location1"
    , Fields!Task_Code.Value >= 6200 and Fields!Task_Code.Value <= 6500, "Location2")
```

[image]

For `Location`, I've assumed that `Task_Code` is integer based; you could always use `CInt` as required if this is not the case.

I've created a table with a Details group and two groups based on the Calculated Fields:

[image]

Results looks like the requirements:

[image]

Comment: Ian you rock. My problem is every time I add a calculated field to the shared data set it doesn't show up as a usable field to add to the table.

Comment: Silly question, but what happens when you click **Refresh Fields** in the report's local Dataset, i.e. the reference to the Shared Dataset?

Comment: so i go into my shared dataset, add the calculated field, then click ok i click refresh fields and then click ok.

when i go to add the group, the new calculated field does not show up :(

Comment: i basically just redid the entire report and the fields show up.